# Angular environment file not copied by ng serve/build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am stuck with this apparently simple issue. I have different env files in `angular-cli.json` as shown:

```
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "local": "environments/environment.local.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
    "test": "environments/environment.test.ts",
    "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts",
    "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

I expect that `ng serve --environment=local` will copy the contents of `environment.local.ts` to `environment.ts` , however it is apparently not working. The app does not work if I have an intentional typo in `environment.ts`. For example, if I have in environment.local.ts `export const baseWebApiUrl = 'http://localhost:63037/api/'` and in `environment.ts` `export const baseWebApiUrl = 'http://xxx/api/'`  - the app fails. It only works if I also have `export const baseWebApiUrl = 'http://localhost:63037/api/'` in `environment.ts` which defeats the purpose of all these different settings files.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

In the component where you want to use that environment variable add below import statement:

`import { environment } from '../environments/environment';`

Then you do a build for your environment:

`ng build -env=local`

If you try ng serve after this, the application will take the values from corresponding environment file. Please try this and share results.

Comment: Hello Balaji, thanks for responding. But your solution did not work - the problem is same as before that the app failed and the correct url is not used

Comment: Be sure that in your component, you import
`import { environment } from './../environments/environment';` instead of
`import { environment } from './../environments/environment.prod'`

The "intelligent" code help imported the latter for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming that ng serve will take the  output of ng build --env=NAME but it seems like need to use both ng build and ng serve with --env=NAME